# Fermat's Little theorem to find primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

---

Find $4$ primes that divide 
$14^{60} - 33^{60}$

---

okay, so the easiest thing to do was to re-write that as $7^{60}2^{60} - 11^{60}3^{60}$.
However, that doesn't really help.
Next step is the little Fermat's theorem, makes sense to try with modulo $2, 3, 7, 11$. However I don't remember how to do that, how to start. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

$$33^{60}-14^{60}$$  is immediately divisible by $33^2-14^2=(33-14)(33+14)$ which are primes

Using Fermat's little theorem $a^{60}\equiv1\pmod p$ for $(a,p)=1$ and if $\phi(p)=p-1$ divides $60$

$\implies a^{60}\equiv b^{60}\pmod p$ for $(ab,p)=1$

Clearly two possible values of  $p$ are $31,61$

Comment: how did you get that

Comment: @Xue, Please find the edited version

Comment: yes, but when I do that for 14-33, I end up with a clearly negative number...is that okay? thank you

Comment: @Xue, If $-19|a,19|a$